# How can i highlight my block of code after type in textarea with highlight.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight.js

i want highlight my block of code with highlight.js when type in textarea and reload highlightjs

```
<script>hljs.initHighlighting.called = false;</script>
<pre><code id="demo" class="html"></code></pre>
<textarea style="width:200px;height:200px;" onkeyup="highlighter(this)">
</textarea>
<script>
String.prototype.toHtmlEntities = function() {
    return this.replace(/./gm, function(s) {
    return "&#" + s.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
    });
};
function highlighter(element){
val = element.value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
hljs.initHighlighting();
}
</script>
```

But this part of my code does not work

Comment: did you find the workaround?

Comment: yes thank you friend